# Object coordinates not updating as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm having an issue with a prefab I'm instantiating in my script. What I'm attempting to do is simulate the physics behind the projectile motion of a cannonball. I have the following script attached to my prefab:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ShootPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

    // vectors & angles to be calculated
    private float fx = 0f;
    private float fy = 0f;
    private float angle;

    // forces acting upon object
    private float gravity = 9.8f;
    private float force = 1.2f;

    // new distance & vector variables
    private float dis_x = 0f;
    private float dis_y = 0f;

    // Script & CannonBall transform
    private CannonPhysics cannon_angle;

    void Start() {
        cannon_angle = GameObject.FindWithTag("Gun").GetComponent<CannonPhysics>();
        angle = cannon_angle.getAngle ();
        fx = Mathf.Round (force * Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle));
        fy = Mathf.Round (force * Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle));
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        dis_x = (float)(fx * Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
        dis_y = (float)(fy + Time.timeSinceLevelLoad + (0.5) * (-gravity) * Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
        Debug.Log (dis_x+", "+dis_y);
        gameObject.transform.Translate (new Vector2(dis_x, dis_y));
    }

}
```

And the prefab will be instantiated from the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CannonPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

    // This will be our script to rotate our cannon
    private float angle = 0f;

    // cannonball object
    public Transform FirePoint;
    GameObject cannon = null;

    void Update() {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            angle = angle + 1;
        }
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            angle = angle - 1;
        }

        // update cannon angle
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3(0, 0, angle));

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            CreateCannon();
        }
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    private void CreateCannon() {
        cannon = Instantiate (Resources.Load("Prefabs/CannonBall"), FirePoint.position, FirePoint.rotation) as GameObject;
        Destroy (cannon, 3f);
    }

}
```

The object gets instantiated as it should, and the object is destroyed after 3 seconds as it should, however the object `x` and `y` position do not change at all, and are not what i should expect them to be. Let me give you an example:

These are the `x` and `y` coordinates i should expect which i have displaying in the console.

[image]

However these are the actual coordinates displayed in Unity's inspector:

[image]

What's strange too, is that these coordinates will not change for each object, they will literally stay the same, even after the object has been destroyed. Can anyone explain why this is happening? And perhaps offer a solution?

**Edit:** For a more clear example:

Each time i instantiate my cannonball object the `x` and `y` coordinates for the next object to be instantiated are referenced from the last. Here are the result of my first instantiated object after being destroyed.

[image]

And here they are after instantiating a second object.

[image]

Now what I'm expecting is that each new object instantiated should start from it "original" position (figuratively speaking) and the `x` and `y` values should reset and start again effectively.

Comment: WIth `Translate`, you are changing the `x` and `y` by the amounts given, not setting them to `x` and `y`. They are relatively small amounts compared to the actual `x` and `y` positions, so maybe you aren't noticing the difference in the game window?

Comment: Thanks, but why are the same `x` and `y` positions being referenced on each new object instantiated? As in if i instantiated an object, the next object will reference the `x` and `y` cords left off by the previous object after is is destroyed.

Comment: Ideally what i want is for each new object instantiated to start from the "original" cords referenced

Comment: The reason they are all being instantiated in the same place is simple -- you are telling `Instantiate` to create them at `FirePoint.position` which never changes.

Comment: Well yes, that's what i want, the problem is each `x` and `y` cord is being referenced from the last object instantiated. I don't think i explained myself very well. I'll attempt to update the OP with a more clear example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things happening in the code you have provided in the `FixedUpdate()` portion of your code which I have copied below:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    dis_x = (float)(fx * Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
    dis_y = (float)(fy + Time.timeSinceLevelLoad + (0.5) * (-gravity) * Time.timeSinceLevelLoad * Time.timeSinceLevelLoad);
    Debug.Log (dis_x+", "+dis_y);
    gameObject.transform.Translate (new Vector2(dis_x, dis_y));
}
```

First, `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` provides you the time, in seconds, that has passed since your level was loaded. What this means for your code is that `dis_x` and `dis_y` always have larger values the longer you have your application open. So, when you spawn a new prefab, the `d_x` and `d_y` values are already at a position that seems as if it's using the position of the last prefab.

Instead, if you want to calculate the new position of an object given it's velocity, you'd typically want to use the deltaTime instead. For example:

```
dx = vel.x * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
dy = vel.y * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```

In this example, `dx` and `dy` represent the change in position given the velocity of the object. `Time.fixedDeltaTime` represents the amount of time in seconds that has passed since the last time `FixedUpdate()` was called. You would then add `dx` and `dy` to your position to get the new position.

Secondly, `gameObject.transform.Translate()` translates the position of the GameObject; it does *not* set the position of the GameObject. Translate will just add the Vector3 to your current position. This is why your debugging output looks so strange; `dis_x` and `dis_y` are not your positions; they are how far you moved the GameObject by calling `Translate()`.

To set the position of the GameObject, do this instead:

```
gameobject.transform.position = newPosition;
```

...where `newPosition` is a Vector3 that represents the new position of your gameobject.

Comment: Thanks, this actually gave me an idea about the timing that i was using. I found a solution by creating a separate variable called `elapsed_time` and passing that instead of `Time.timeSinceLevelLoad` and updating it with `Time.fixedDeltaTime` on each update run. It now runs exactly as expected!